# Get the subset of a parameter pack based on a given set of indices

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Okay, this is a really difficult one.

I want to be able to get the subset of a parameter pack by choosing the parameter types at a given set of valid indices and then use that parameter pack as the argument list of a function. IE:

```
template <size_t... indices_t>
void func(pack_subset<indices_t..., args_t...>); //incorrect syntax,
                                                 //not sure how else to write this
                                                 //args_t is predetermined, this
                                                 //function is a static member of
                                                 //a variadic class template

//For a parameter pack <float, double> and index set 0
void func(float); // <- result of template
```

I can get the type of a single index, but a set of indices is a bit harder, especially when that set is of a variable size.  The syntax for that is:

```
pack_index<size_t index_t, typename... args>::type
```

Maybe I can string a bunch of these together, but I'm not sure how to go about expanding indices_t so that I get a pack_index for each value in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap the arguments into a tuple, it's pretty straight-forward:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, std::size_t ...Is>
struct selector
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>;
};
```

Example input: `<int, double, float, char, bool>, 1, 3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <demangle.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << demangle<selector<std::tuple<int, double, float, char, bool>, 1, 3>::type>()
        << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
std::tuple<double, char>
```

All you need to do is use `std::tuple<args_t...>` where you have just `args_t...` at the moment.

---

Here's an alternative idea for structuring that idea into something easier to handle:

```
template <typename ...Args> struct selector
{
    using T = std::tuple<Args...>;

    template <std::size_t ...Is>
    static void call(typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type ...args)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
selector<int, char, bool, double>::call<0, 2>(1, true);   // int, bool
```

Comment: Ah, can you explain the using keyword in this context?  I've never seen it used this way.

Comment: @NmdMystery: It's the same as saying `typedef std::tuple<...> type;`. New in C++11.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble implementing this, although the struct template compiles.  This is what I have: `template<size_t... indices_t> void func(selector<std::tuple<args_t...>, indices_t...>)`  This also compiles, I'm just not sure how to provide arguments because code completion isn't really helping me out in Visual Studio

Comment: @NmdMystery: You forgot the `::type` at the end, and probably `typename` at the front.

Comment: So with that, do I provide a tuple?  The function is asking for one argument, but the proper tuple doesn't work.

Comment: Wait, nevermind.  The tuple does work.  One caveat though - can I remove the tuple wrapper so all I need to write is `func<0>(4.5f)` instead of `func<0>(std::tuple<float>(4.5f))`?

Comment: @NmdMystery: You should probably wrap a static function into a class template and specialize that partially for tuples, and make a separate, auxiliary function to call the static class template function.

Comment: @KerrekSB Alright, thanks so much for the help!  I was trying to do this for over a day :P

Comment: @NmdMystery: I added an alternative implementation using static class template member templates.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm getting an internal compiler error when I try to do that, is that GCC only?

Comment: This is how I have it written out: `template <size_t... indices_t> static void call(typename std::tuple_element<indices_t, std::tuple<args_t...> >::type... args) {}`

Comment: I tried making the conversion internally within the class I'm using this for too, and I get the same error.

Comment: @NmdMystery: An internal compiler error is a bug in your compiler, completely independent of the code. It works with GCC 4.8 for me, if that helps.

Comment: I'll try moving this to GCC and get back to you then.

Comment: @KerrekSB Alright, it works!  MinGW has a bit of a problem (version is probably out of date) but on linux it compiles perfectly.