# Passing std::integer_sequence as template parameter to a meta function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How can I pass an `std::integer_sequence` as a template parameter to a meta function (i.e. not a function template)?

Given e.g. the following use case (but not limited to it):

I want to use a integer sequence to remove the last `N` types from a parameter pack. I thought I could use `selector` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19759105/678093), but I fail to pass the integer sequence to this meta function.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct selector
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct remove_last_n
{
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-N>;  
    using type = typename selector<std::tuple<Ts...>, Indices>::type; // fails
};

int main()
{
    using X = remove_last_n<2, int, char, bool, int>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<X, std::tuple<int, char>>::value, "types do not match");
}
```

**compiler error**

```
main.cpp:15:55: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression

using type = typename selector<std::tuple<Ts...>, Indices>::type; // fails

                                                  ^~~~~~~

main.cpp:5:38: note: template parameter is declared here

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
```

[<kbd>live on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8d1efd56d529309)

How would I pass the integer sequence?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to (partially) specialize `selector` so that indices are deduced from `std::index_sequence`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct selector;

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct selector<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct remove_last_n
{
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-N>;  
    using type = typename selector<std::tuple<Ts...>, Indices>::type;
};

int main()
{
    using X = remove_last_n<2, int, char, bool, int>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<X, std::tuple<int, char>>::value, "types do not match");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a87c38513df2eb9)

Answer (score 1):

For a use case this simple, you can also write the metafunction as a function template instead.

```
template<class...> class wrapper{};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>
    selector_impl(wrapper<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>);    

template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct remove_last_n
{
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-N>;  
    using type = decltype(selector_impl(wrapper<std::tuple<Ts...>, Indices>()));
};
```

Incidentally, the `tuple_element` implementation of `selector` is generally quite inefficient, because the number of recursive template instantiations required is quadratic. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493314/2756719) shows one way to make the number of template instantiations required linear in the number of types in the list.