# Generate Integer Sequence For Template Parameter Pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, parameter-pack

There is a class method template with parameter pack I want to call, defined as:

```
class C {
   template<int ... prp> void function() {}
}
```

For a given integer N, I need all integers up to N as template arguments for the parameter pack.

```
constexpr int N = 2;

C c;
c.function<0, 1>();
```

I have tried using std::integer_sequence, but it can't be used here.

```
c.function<std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>>();
```

I also found this answer: [Passing std::integer_sequence as template parameter to a meta function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893102/passing-stdinteger-sequence-as-template-parameter-to-a-meta-function) Could I pass the function inside the partial specialization, e.g. using std::function? I was not able to use template arguments with std::function.

Additionally, the class has multiple function I would like to call the same way.

```
c.function1<0, 1>();
c.function2<0, 1>();
```

There must be a nice way to solve this but I wasn't successful yet. Still trying to understand TMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create helper function:

```
template <int... Is>
void helper(C& c, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    c.function1<Is...>();
    c.function2<Is...>();
}
```

And call it

```
constexpr int N = 2;
C c;

helper(c, std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>());
```

Answer (score 1):

What about passing the `std::integer_sequence` as argument?

I mean something as follows

```
class C {
   template <int ... prp>
   void function (std::integer_sequence<int, prp...>)
   { /* ... */ }
}
```

that you can call using `std::make_integer_sequence`

```
constexpr int N = 2;

C c;

// this call function<0, 1>(std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1>);
// the prp variadic list (0, 1, in this case) is deduced
c.function(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{});
```

(caution: code not tested)

Comment: The problem is, the class is part of a framework. So I can't change the class or function. Would you suggest to write a wrapper function?

Comment: If you can't change the function... yes, a wrapper function can be a solution. See also the Jarod42's answer.